# Are finite extensions of matrix groups also matrix groups?

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be a group and $n$ a positive integer.
I have two related questions:

1. If $K\leq G$ is finite and $G/K$ embeds in $SL_n(\mathbb{Z})$, does $G$ necessarily embed in $SL_d(\mathbb{Z})$ for some $d$?
2. If $K\leq G$ embeds in $SL_n(\mathbb{Z})$ and $G/K$ is finite, does $G$ necessarily embed in $SL_d(\mathbb{Z})$ for some $d$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to Question 2 is yes, and there is no need to assume that $K$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. The induced representation from $K$ to $G$ provides an embedding into ${\rm GL}_d({\mathbb Z})$ with $d = n|G:K|$, and from that you get an embedding into ${\rm SL}_d({\mathbb Z})$ with $d=n|G:K|+1$.

I am not sure about Question 1.

Comment: The answer to Question 1 is no if you replace ${\mathbb Z}$ by ${\mathbb C}$. See Simon Thomas' answer to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/22814/

Comment: It does answer negatively Question. Indeed the same result of Deligne works in the $\mathbf{Z}$ case, at least for $n\ge 4$. Namely some finite covering of $\mathrm{Sp}_4(\mathbf{Z})$ is not linear.